# d3.event.y has strange values during drag behavior

Tags: d3.js, drag

I'm creating an example illustrating a layout with resizeable cells using the D3 drag behaviour and CSS `{display: table}` styles. It works fine for dragging horizontally, but not vertically. For vertical resizing, `d3.event.y` is providing values that do not make sense to me.

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LqMn5/5/) showing the working horizontal drag and the broken vertical drag. Take a look at the console output while dragging to see that the values returned by `d3.event` match the values returned by `d3.mouse()` for the horizontal drag, but they diverge for the vertical drag.

I can fix the behaviour by using the `d3.mouse()` y-coordinate instead of the `d3.event` y-coordinate. To see this, comment out the "DOESN'T WORK" line and uncomment the "WORKS" line. However, I don't understand why I need to do this, and it seems less general in that I have to assume a mouse input instead of using the more generic d3.event.

Is this a bug, or am I failing to understand something here?

Note that [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23936524/d3-drag-behavior-not-working-properly-on-html-elements) seems to be hitting the same issue, but using HTML tables instead of CSS tables. I thought it would be helpful to document that this problem is occurring in both contexts.

Also note that commenting out the two lines that actually do the vertical resizing, commented with "RESIZE CELLS", makes the `d3.event` work correctly. Of course, the table doesn't get resized then. This suggests that it is something about the act of resizing the divs that is leading `d3.event` astray.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright, I think I've figured out the issue. If you look at [the code](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/blob/master/src/behavior/drag.js) for drag behavior, you'll notice in `dragstart` that the value used to calculate the mouse offset is based off `this.parentNode`. In short, it uses `this.parentNode` as a reference point, and assumes that it's going to be stable for the duration of the drag. You're modifying the parent nodes during the drag, so its reference point gets, to put it technically, pretty borked. In this case, using `d3.mouse` is your best bet, since `d3.event.y` is only going to be reliable as long as the parent node stays in place.

The reason this only happens in the y direction for you is that the x position of all the rows, which are the parent nodes here, stay constant, whereas the y component changes during the drag.

The relevant code sections:

```
parent = that.parentNode,
```

```
function moved() {
    var position1 = position(parent, dragId), dx, dy;

    //...

    dispatch({
      type: "drag",
      x: position1[0] + dragOffset[0],
      y: position1[1] + dragOffset[1],
      dx: dx,
      dy: dy
    });
```

Comment: Thanks. This is definitely the issue. I've created another [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t3L2t/3/) to illustrate this in as simple a way as I could think of: a div that can be dragged around by a child div that acts as a "drag handle". Since the `d3.event` coordinates are relative to the parent node, they can't be used in this case.