# D3 drag event behaviour: DragEvent.x and DragEvent.y values source

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, drag-and-drop

I don't understand the behaviour of the D3 DragEvent object in Mike Bostock’s examples for D3.

Those are the two examples I don't understand:
[Circle Dragging I](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/22994cc97fefaeede0d861e6815a847e)
[Drag + Zoom](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/6123708)

This is the code that I don't understand:

> function dragged(d) {   d3.select(this).attr("cx", d.x =
>   d3.event.x).attr("cy", d.y = d3.event.y); }

In this example, d.x and d.y are part of a data object that contains the last centre of the circle.

What I expect to happen with this code, is that the attributes cx and cy of the circle change to the current value of d3.event.x and d3.event.y

In my view, that should be the coordinates where the mouse is when the user start dragging. If the user is not starting to drag exactly in the centre of the circle, the behaviour I expect is the circle to jump to the place where the user start dragging and, then, a normal dragging behaviour.

My problem is that the initial jump doesn't happen and I don't know why.

I checked the values of d3.event.x and d3.event.y when the code is running and they are exactly the same values of d.x and d.y, never mind where the user click in the circle. I don't understand why that is the case.

Finally, I changed the name (and only the name) in the object (and whenever was necessary in the code), from d.x and d.y to d.m and d.n and the code started to do what I was expecting.

> function dragged(d) {   d3.select(this).attr("cx", d.m =
>   d3.event.x).attr("cy", d.n = d3.event.y); }

So, the code works differently when the data object has the properties d.x and d.y that when the data object has the properties d.m and d.n.
It seems like the object DragEvent is expecting a data object with concrete proprieties but that sounds weird to me and I can't find it documented.

I was expecting to avoid checking D3 source code if somebody know the answer already.

Comment: Mike Bostocks's examples are using version 3 of D3.  There currently is a version 4 which may cause the differences you are experiencing, if you are testing in v4.

Comment: The examples linked in my question use src="//d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js", so, I don't think that's the problem. I have checked it and I confirm it's not a version problem. Anyway, I'm not experiencing differences with the example. It's just that I don't understand why it works, and why it doesn't work if you change the name of the properties of the data object.

Comment: related questions:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23936524/d3-drag-behavior-not-working-properly-on-html-elements

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25075402/d3-event-y-has-strange-values-during-drag-behavior

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I though a weird behaviour is the intended behaviour.

All DragEvent objects have a 'subject'. The subject is not the SVG shape that is producing the dragging event, but, if it exist, the datum associated to that SVG.

More information available in: https://github.com/d3/d3-drag#drag_subject

So, yes, if the datum object have the the properties x and y, the value would be assigned to the properties dx and dy of the DragEvent object.

As we can see in the d3 source, in the [drag.js](https://github.com/d3/d3-drag/blob/bb0af439b186b90e51c18057e2f616e02144b56a/src/drag.js#L110-L111) file:

```
  dx = s.x - p[0] || 0;
  dy = s.y - p[1] || 0;
```